# How to insert and update value into database table php

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in PHP and i want to insert value into my database table for my drop-down value using PHP insert query, I am having an error to insert data and also want to update the existence value of database table when insert new value into database table, here is my code help me to solve it, My Code is below :

```
<?php 
include 'dbconfig.php'; 
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sales Panel App</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" name="myForm" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table border="1">
 <tr>
<td>Sales Person List</td>
<td>
<?php


 $sql="select name,id from sales order by name"; 
    echo "<select name = 'salelist' value=''>Sales Person Name</option>";
    echo "<option value = 'Select Sales Person' selected>Select Sales    Person</option>";
   {
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
    echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[name]</option>"; 
   }
    echo "</select>";
   }
    echo "<br>";

   ?>

   </td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>No of Panels</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="panelnumber" size="1"></td>
    </tr>



   </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submitdata"></p>
    </form>
  <?php

     $salelist = $_POST['salelist'];
     $panelnumber = $_POST['panelnumber'];

        $sql2 = "select * from sales where name = $salelist";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql2);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $oldvalue = $panelnumber;
          $newvalue = $oldvalue + $panelnumber;
          $query = 'update sales where name = $panelnumber';
       }
         else {
         $qry = "insert into sales (id, name, panelnumber) values ('', $salelist, $panelnumber)";
        }
        ?>


            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Couple general points, check first that `$_POST['salelist']` is set using `if(isset($_POST['salelist']))`, you will avoid warnings this way. Second, move all that code you have there that inserts below database connection. Try to do business logic before output to browser.

Comment: Third, don't do this `"select * from sales where name = $salelist"`, it's insecure. Last, if you do that, you need single quotes around `$salelist`

Comment: Best to use bind parameter functions when inserting data submitted by users. If you do as you have now (`"select * from sales where name = $salelist"` and `"insert into sales (id, name, panelnumber) values ('', $salelist, $panelnumber)"`, and `'update sales where name = $panelnumber'`), you are open to sql injection.

Comment: Lastly, you don't seem to run the `$qry` or `$query` at the bottom. You actually have to run the sql in a query.

Comment: Also, what is `$conn`? That seems to be a whole different connection?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
$query = 'update sales where name = $panelnumber';
```

You are not saying what to update. You have to use one of the methods available to update an SQL row.

For example, a correct one should be:

```
$query = "update sales set city='rio' where name = '$panelnumber'";
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) is the official MySQL Documentation.
And you have one more error, if you write this:

```
$number = 5;
$variable = '$number';
echo $variable;
```

The output of `$variable` will not be "5", will be "$number", literally. If you want to set a variable in a string, you must us double quote (**"**) not single quote (**'**) because single quote will literally save what is between them, and double will try to "translate" variables and other stuff.
The correct way would be:

```
$number = 5;
$variable = "$number";
echo $variable;
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) you have a detailed PHP official explanation about what I am describing.